# Update relationship properties in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher

I'm using `Neo4j` gem with only `ActiveNode`. I'm able to create a relationship property but how do I access and update it?

I can write the entire thing as a cypher query using `Neo4j::ActiveBase.current_session.query('Cypher Query')`

But how do I write it without using `cypher`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have, say, a `Person` model with a `friends` association, you could do one of the following

```
Person.friends.each_rel do |rel|
end

Person.friends.each_rel.map do |rel|
end # or any other `Enumerable` method

Person.friends.each_rel.to_a
```

There is also an `each_with_rel` which gives both the node and the relationship